# php for loop is not returning all values, why?

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli

I started learning PHP and Databases today.

What I tried so far and worked is to access information from a database using a simple **updateScores.php** file.

DB high_scores:

---

```
  names  | scores |
___________________
 player1 |  20    |

 player2 |  69    |
```

My code:

```
$host="localhost";
$database="players";
$user="root";
$password = "";
$error = "Cant connect";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysqli_select_db($con, $database) or die("Unable to connect!");

$query = "SELECT * FROM high_scores";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$n = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){

    $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["name"];
    $score = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["score"];
    echo "Name  : ".$name;
    echo "Score : ".$score;
}
?>
```

This works fine when i execute http://localhost/updateScores.php

However when i change the last two lines to

```
echo $name."\t";
echo $score."\n";
```

I only get the first name (player1) and the last score (69)
Why this is happening? Any help and additional link would be great. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use: `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` for it to work in browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your `for` loop has two calls to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, each of which fetches a new row from the database:

```
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["name"];
$score = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["score"];
```

So you will end up getting the name from one row with the score from the next. The normal way of writing this loop is using `while`, with the fetch as the condition for the loop and then accessing the individual values from the fetched row:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $row["name"];
    $score = $row["score"];
    echo "Name  : ".$name;
    echo "Score : ".$score;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQLi result is traversable. You could simply use `foreach`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "Name  : ".$row['name'];
    echo "Score : ".$row['score'];
}
```